# Bullets WILL NOT dissapear in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, styles, html-lists

Hoping you can help me with a problem. I cannot get rid of Bullets in Firefox, i don't want any anywhere, hence my list-style-type: none!important being everywhere. It only appears in Firefox as far as i can tell.

the HTML....

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
 <head>
    <title>littleprints.nl</title>
    <meta name="description" content="----" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="----" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/slimbox2.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slimbox2.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="layout.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
 </head>
 <body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="inline1">
         <div id="mainpic">
            <img src="myimages/circle.jpg" width="100%" alt="Circle bracelet"/>
         </div>
         <div id="intro">
            <p>Hi and welcome to little prints NL. we make this and that all by hand with 100% silver. my name is Donna Burns and i work by commision, ive been studying for 4 years and am currently learning to become a goldsmith.</p>
         </div>
      </div>

      <div id="inline2">
         <p>Click for more...</p>
         <div id="images">
            <a href="myimages/photos/dogtag.jpg" rel="lightbox-gal" title="Beautiful, isn't it?" ><img src="myimages/work/chunky.gif" alt="chunky"/></a>
            <a href="myimages/photos/hearts.jpg" rel="lightbox-gal" title="Beautiful, isn't it?" ><img src="myimages/work/hearts.gif" alt="hearts"/></a>        
            <a href="myimages/photos/close.jpg" rel="lightbox-gal" title="Beautiful, isn't it?" ><img src="myimages/work/close.gif" alt="close"/></a>       
            <a href="myimages/photos/pearl.jpg" rel="lightbox-gal" title="Beautiful, isn't it?" >&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="myimages/photos/flower.jpg" rel="lightbox-gal" title="Beautiful, isn't it?" >&nbsp;</a>
            <a href="myimages/photos/frontcircle.jpg" rel="lightbox-gal" title="Beautiful, isn't it?" >&nbsp;</a>       
            <a href="myimages/photos/dogtag.jpg" rel="lightbox-gal" title="Beautiful, isn't it?" >&nbsp;</a> 

        </div>
     </div>

</div><!--end container-->

<div id="footer">
    <div id="footalign">

       <div id="social">

         <ul>
            <li>
              <a href="http://www.facebook.com/littleprints" title="Little Prints">
                 <img src="myimages/facebook.png" width="50px" height="50px" alt="FB"/>
              </a>
           </li>
           <li>
             <a href="contact.html" title="contact">
                <img src="myimages/at.gif" alt="@"/>
             </a>
           </li>
        </ul>


      </div>

      <div id="contact">
         <p><br/>To enquire about a charm either phone:<br/> 0787463289<br/> or use one of the methods to the side.</p>
      </div>


    </div>
 </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

the CSS...

```
* {margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;}

html, body {
    background-color: #000000;image;
    text-align: center;
    font: 16px/1.8 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    list-style-type: none!important;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#container {
    position: relative;
    width: 900px;
    top: 0;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    background-image: URL(myimages/back2.gif);
    margin-bottom: 180px;
}

#footer {
    background-color: #555555;
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 900px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 22px;
    margin-top: -180px;
}

#inline1{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#inline2 {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#mainpic {
    float: left;
    width: 68%;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#intro {
    float: right;
    width: 20%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#images {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

#footalign {
    display: inline;
    width:900px;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#contact {
    text-align: center;
    background-color:#555555;
    float: middle;
    list-style-type: none;
}

#social{
    background-color:#555555;
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    padding:0;
    padding-right: 5px;
    text-align:center;
    list-style-type: none!important;
}

#social  img{
    border: none;
    list-style-type: none!important;
    margin: 3px;
}

#social ul{
    border: none;
    list-style-type: none!important;
}

#social a{
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-transition:all .5s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:all .5s ease-out;
    -ms-transition:all .5s ease-out;
    -o-transition:all .5s ease-out;
    transition:all .5s ease-out;
    list-style-type: none!important;
}

#social a:hover{
    display:inline-block;
    -webkit-transform:translate(-10px,0px);
    -moz-transform:translate(0px,-10px);
    -ms-transform:translate(-10px,0px);
    -o-transform:translate(-10px,0px);
    transform:translate(-10px,0px);
    list-style-type: none!important;
}

#form {
    margin-top: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.nav1
    {font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 22px;text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #000000;}
    a:link {text-decoration:none; color:#000000; padding:3px;}
    a:visited {text-decoration:none; color:#000000;}
    a:active {text-decoration:none; color:#555555;}
    a:hover {text-decoration:none; color:#555555;}

.nav2
    {font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 22px;text-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #ffffff;}
    a:link {text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff; padding:3px;}
    a:visited {text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff;}
    a:active {text-decoration:none; color:#555555;}
    a:hover {text-decoration:none; color:#555555;}

.p1 {
    color: #ffffff;
}

div#images img {
    max-width: 500px;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: The `list-style` properties go on either the list (`ul` or `ol`) or on the list-items themselves (`li`).  This applicable to any element set to `display: list-item`

Comment: Please clean up your code and scan for typos first... `#inilne2` and `background-color: #000000;image;`. Is this at all what your page looks like (without broken images)? I cleaned up the code a bit. http://jsfiddle.net/LhF7V/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
#social ul {
border: none;
list-style: none!important;
}
```

Just using `list-style` might simplify it. But anyway, I'm in Firefox, and I didn't see any bullet points.

You might want to try setting up a test case in jsFiddle for us. Just posting code like this is sometimes a needle in a haystack!

http://jsfiddle.net/

Good luck.

PS - Putting `list-style` on the code below makes no sense, since you're specifying an `img` tag!

```
#social img {
border: none;
list-style-type: none!important;
margin: 3px;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

For arguments sake (because I can't see exactly how your app is working), try setting a global default style for your lists like so:

```
ul, ol { list-style: none; }
```

Also, I know that in some older browsers, setting this on the actual li itself also helps (I could be wrong though):

```
li { list-style: none; }
```

Comment: hi tried your suggestion, dosn't seem to have made a difference, Oops thank you for pointing that out I think I've been awake too long!!

Comment: sorry keep pushing enter! ha. Its live now at Jamfinder.co.uk if anybody could do me a favor and check it on their browsers pretty please. hoping its just a problem for me!

Comment: @DunlopBurns I just put this in your code and it worked: 
#social ul { list-style: none; }

Comment: ok, thanks guys, I'm going to try it in an hour or so just in case it hasn't uploaded yet! thanks guys your all stars!

Comment: Thank you guys i was being stupid again!! until next time.

Comment: @DunlopBurns No worries! Happens to all of us at times. Think about accepting an answer or perhaps answer your own question and mark it as such. This helps the community get answers quickly in future. Thanks.